# If $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ Does it mean $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

If $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ $\forall$ $x \in Dom(f)$, Then Does it mean $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$

> **My question:**
>    Are there any other functions whose inverse is itself?

Comment: $f: x\mapsto x^{-1}$ with $\operatorname{dom} f = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. There are many other functions. Is there any restriction to the domain? In $\mathbb{R}^2$ every mirror function would work.

Answer (score 3):

$${\displaystyle f(x)=\ln \left({\frac {e^{x}+1}{e^{x}-1}}\right).}$$

check that $$f\circ f(x)=x$$

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Take $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\-x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

You know that the graph of $y=f^{-1}(x)$ is the graph of $y=f(x)$ flipped about the line $y=x$, right?

So any function whose graph is symmetric around the line $y=x$ will be its own inverse.  So things like $y=1/x$ and $y= 3-x$ all work.

Answer (score 1):

Or take $\;f(x):=\cfrac1x\;,\;\;x\in (0,\infty)\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be two disjoint subsets of $\Bbb R$ of equal cardinality, which means that there exists a bijection $g\colon A\to B$. Define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&x\in A\\g^{-1}(x)&x\in B\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is its own inverse. On the other hand, every involution of $\Bbb R$ is of this form (we can let $A=\{\,x\in \Bbb R\mid f(x)<x\,\}$, $B=\{\,x\in \Bbb R\mid f(x)>x\,\}$).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it means that domain and codomain of $f$ coincide and that $f\circ f$ equals the identity function on this set.

The function $f$ is a so-called [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)).

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)#Pre-calculus) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest examples are in the form 
$$
\text{a symmetric expression in }x,y=\text{const}.
$$
The expressions $x+y$, $xy$ and $e^x+y^y-e^{x+y}$ has already been mentioned. You can try to figure out other, for example, $x^2+y^2$ gives the function
$$
x^2+y^2=C\quad\Rightarrow\quad y=f(x)=\sqrt{C-x^2}.
$$
Do not forget to describe the domain of the function.